# MGTwitterEngine getting feeds - iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter

So, in my app, I am trying to use MGTwitterEngine to read from a certain user on Twitter, and then log the recent posts in an array. Is it possible to do this with this library? I am trying to do this without logging in. Any help would be appreciate, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with `MGTwitterEngine`. You do it this way:

```
MGTwitterEngine *twitterng = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[twitterng getUserTimelineFor:@"userName" sinceID:0 startingAtPage:0 count:8];
```

and it will call delegate method

```
- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the feed url that contains the rss feeds. You don't need to login for that. Use MGTwitterEngine to get the tweets and set them into array. Then you simply need to reload the tableview.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup